# Trying to webscrape odds from site

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape 'https://www.oddschecker.com/football/germany/bundesliga/wolfsburg-v-eintracht-frankfurt/winner' this page (or any other like it on the website) for the 'both teams to score' odds.

This is what I have so far

```
url = 'https://www.oddschecker.com/football/spain/la-liga-primera/levante-v-rayo-vallecano/winner'

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

webpage = urlopen(req).read()

page_soup = soup(webpage, 'html.parser')
```

```
btts = page_soup.find_all('div', class_='full-bleed-wrapper MarketWrapper_mgnb13w')[13]
print(btts)
```

But this is where I get stuck as I can't seem to dive down to 'button' where the odds are.

Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The numbers you see on the page is loaded dynamically with JavaScript (so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see them). You can use next example how to simulate the dynamic request:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.oddschecker.com/football/spain/la-liga-primera/levante-v-rayo-vallecano/winner"
req = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

market_id = page_soup.select_one('h2:-soup-contains("Both Teams To Score")')
market_id = market_id["aria-controls"]

api_url = (
    "https://www.oddschecker.com/api/markets/v2/all-odds?market-ids={}&repub=OC"
)

data = requests.get(api_url.format(market_id)).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# df_bets = pd.json_normalize(data[0]["bets"])
# print(df_bets)

df_odds = pd.json_normalize(data[0]["odds"])
print(df_odds)
```

Prints:

```
          betId bookmakerCode  oddsDecimal oddsFractional oddsUs                                                            bookmakerSelectionId  status movement  eachWay  eachWayDenominator  eachWayPlaces             betFeedTimestamp inOut inOutChange
0   26800267296            SK     3.500000            5/2    250                                                       905375896*59*28150512*5/2  ACTIVE    -0.25    False                   0              0     2021-09-07T12:44:47.029Z   out       -0.25
1   26800267296            EE     3.450000          49/20    245                                                                      6306209648  ACTIVE    +0.05    False                   0              0     2021-09-07T12:38:08.776Z    in       +0.05
2   26800267204            WH     4.400000           17/5    340         3314095633*992686788*Levante*Match+Result+and+Both+Teams+To+Score*false  ACTIVE    +0.07    False                   0              0     2021-09-07T12:27:49.609Z    in       +0.07
3   26800267204            FB     4.333334           10/3    333                                                            214865*924.274512130  ACTIVE    +0.13    False                   0              0     2021-09-03T09:49:05.545Z    in       +0.13
4   26800267204            PP     4.333334           10/3    333                                                            214865*927.146755960  ACTIVE    +0.13    False                   0              0     2021-09-03T09:49:23.595Z    in       +0.13
5   26800267204            SK     4.333334         100/30    333                                                    905375886*59*28150512*100/30  ACTIVE             False                   0              0     2021-09-06T09:52:03.916Z                  
6   26800267204            B3     4.330000           10/3    333  2092734890*106731205*Soccer*106731205*B3F90A267EC31D8BF4F7FF30A5C3D02C2917F802  ACTIVE             False                   0              0     2021-09-07T04:04:41.927Z                  
7   26800267204            FR     4.330000           10/3    333                                                 10*3*159105085.20*1091224276.20  ACTIVE             False                   0              0     2021-09-03T06:20:06.525Z                  
8   26800267204            EE     4.250000           13/4    325                                                                      6306209647  ACTIVE    +0.05    False                   0              0     2021-09-07T12:38:08.776Z    in       +0.05
9   26800267204            BY     4.200000           16/5    320                                             21512675.1*189770761.1*1357637677.1  ACTIVE    +0.20    False                   0              0     2021-09-07T14:14:03.361Z    in       +0.20
10  26800267204            SI     4.200000           16/5    320                                football*spain-primera-division*775212*367102865  ACTIVE    -0.05    False                   0              0     2021-09-02T06:41:51.322Z   out       -0.05
11  26800267204            VC     4.200000           16/5    320                                               6320610.105286032500.530000911886  ACTIVE    -0.13    False                   0              0     2021-09-07T13:19:30.309Z   out       -0.13
12  26800267141            VC     4.750000           15/4    375                                               6320610.105286032800.529952778757  ACTIVE             False                   0              0     2021-09-03T11:07:16.837Z                  
13  26800267141            SI     4.700000          37/10    370                                football*spain-primera-division*775212*367102869  ACTIVE    +0.05    False                   0              0     2021-09-02T06:41:51.395Z    in       +0.05
14  26800267141            WH     4.600000           18/5    360            3314095639*992686788*Draw*Match+Result+and+Both+Teams+To+Score*false  ACTIVE    +0.10    False                   0              0     2021-09-07T12:27:50.506Z    in       +0.10
15  26800267141            B3     4.500000            7/2    350  2092734892*106731205*Soccer*106731205*B786A6C56C8B974A78D9BAD863B067DF54F276E7  ACTIVE             False                   0              0     2021-09-07T04:04:41.934Z                  
16  26800267141            EE     4.500000            7/2    350                                                                      6306209649  ACTIVE             False                   0              0     2021-09-07T12:38:08.776Z                  
17  26800267141            FR     4.500000            7/2    350                                                  7*2*159105085.20*1091224274.20  ACTIVE             False                   0              0     2021-09-03T06:20:06.525Z                  
18  26800267141            SK     4.500000            7/2    350                                                       905375889*59*28150512*7/2  ACTIVE    +0.17    False                   0              0      2021-09-07T12:44:47.03Z    in       +0.17
19  26800267141            WA     4.500000            7/2    350                                                     781872749*202013791*8178269  ACTIVE             False                   0              0     2021-09-07T12:25:16.163Z                  
20  26800267141            FB     4.333334           10/3    333                                                            151478*924.274512130  ACTIVE    +0.13    False                   0              0     2021-09-03T09:49:05.544Z    in       +0.13
21  26800267141            PP     4.333334           10/3    333                                                            151478*927.146755960  ACTIVE    -0.17    False                   0              0     2021-09-03T00:02:28.432Z   out       -0.17
22  26800267141            BY     4.330000           10/3    333                                             21512675.1*189770761.1*1357637678.1  ACTIVE    +0.13    False                   0              0     2021-09-07T14:14:03.377Z    in       +0.13
23  26800267141            VT     4.150000          41/13    315                                                             18495007*2336849385  ACTIVE    +0.10    False                   0              0     2021-09-07T14:41:47.833Z    in       +0.10
24  26800267187            EE     6.300000          53/10    530                                                                      6306209644  ACTIVE    +0.10    False                   0              0     2021-09-07T12:38:08.776Z    in       +0.10
25  26800267187            SK     6.000000            5/1    500                                                       905375902*59*28150512*5/1  ACTIVE             False                   0              0     2021-09-06T09:52:03.916Z                  
26  26800267318            WH     7.500000           13/2    650       3314095643*992686788*Vallecano*Match+Result+and+Both+Teams+To+Score*false  ACTIVE    +0.50    False                   0              0     2021-09-07T12:27:52.616Z    in       +0.50
27  26800267318            B3     7.000000            6/1    600  2092734894*106731205*Soccer*106731205*AE9F693032CEF0361A3B091EBB0A63AE217343C2  ACTIVE             False                   0              0     2021-09-07T04:04:41.932Z                  
28  26800267318            FR     7.000000            6/1    600                                                  6*1*159105085.20*1091224278.20  ACTIVE    +0.50    False                   0              0      2021-09-05T20:28:01.22Z    in       +0.50
29  26800267318            SK     7.000000            6/1    600                                                       905375892*59*28150512*6/1  ACTIVE    +0.50    False                   0              0      2021-09-07T12:44:47.03Z    in       +0.50
30  26800267318            VC     7.000000            6/1    600                                               6320610.105286033200.529956789555  ACTIVE             False                   0              0     2021-09-03T10:53:08.351Z                  
31  26800267318            EE     6.800000           29/5    580                                                                      6306209646  ACTIVE    +0.05    False                   0              0     2021-09-07T12:38:08.776Z    in       +0.05
32  26800267318            BY     6.500000           11/2    550                                             21512675.1*189770761.1*1357637679.1  ACTIVE             False                   0              0     2021-09-07T14:14:03.377Z                  
33  26800267318            FB     6.500000           11/2    550                                                             10779*924.274512130  ACTIVE             False                   0              0  2021-09-01T08:57:57.259568Z                  
34  26800267318            PP     6.500000           11/2    550                                                             10779*927.146755960  ACTIVE    -0.50    False                   0              0     2021-09-03T09:49:23.595Z   out       -0.50
35  26800267318            SI     6.200000           26/5    520                                football*spain-primera-division*775212*367102867  ACTIVE    +0.20    False                   0              0     2021-09-02T06:41:51.479Z    in       +0.20
36  26800267159            VT    10.100000          91/10    910                                                             18495007*2336849380  ACTIVE    +1.20    False                   0              0     2021-09-07T14:41:47.833Z    in       +1.20
37  26800267159            SK    10.000000            9/1    900                                                       905375899*59*28150512*9/1  ACTIVE             False                   0              0     2021-09-06T09:52:02.815Z                  
38  26800267159            EE     9.500000           17/2    850                                                                      6306209645  ACTIVE    -0.75    False                   0              0     2021-09-07T12:38:08.776Z   out       -0.75
```

Comment: Thanks for that! So in the answer it would appear it get the results for 'match result and both teams to score' rather than just 'both teams to score'. How would you go about pulling that data. In an ideal world the end product would be a data frame with 6 columns (teams_playing, best_yes_odds, bookies_for_yes, best_no_odds, bookies_for_no odds, datetime_of_game). Thank you again, I haven't came across this kind of issue before.

Comment: I have just had a little fiddle with it and found the below code gives me the both teams to score                                                                                                 
```market_id = page_soup.select('h2:-soup-contains("Both Teams To Score")')[1]
market_id = market_id["aria-controls"]``` I would still appreciate any guidance on getting it into the dataframe I mentioned above